# Add certificate to trusted does not work via macos "security add-trusted-cert"

Tags: ssl, certificate, macos-catalina, trusted

I have a safari web-page connecting to secured web socket server (written with C# netcore 3.0).
I add server sertificate to trusted running this command (the same certificate I put on my websocket end point).

```
security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain certificate.crt
```

Everything seems valid (I have a blue cross near my certificate in Keys application)
but when I connect from safari (catalina os, mojave os) I get an error

```
OSStatus Error -9807. Invalid certificate chain
```

Also when I import certificate manually via Keys Application GUI there is no error. Everything works.

1. Can anyone explain is there any difference between "security add-trusted-cert" import and GUI manual import?
2. Maybe my add-trusted-cert command is wrong and I need some additional params?

Answer (score 0):

This syntax works perfectly for me on MacOS Catalina, however, it must be run with elevated privileges (sudo or whatever).

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain <MY_CERTIFICATE_FILE.pem>
```